# Multi Select UI Field in user form magento2

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, adminform, ui-select

I am showing multiselect dropdown in user form in admin panel(System->All user->Add User)
I have created a plugin for creating field in that form. Here is the code, I am using:

```
public function aroundGetFormHtml(
    \Magento\User\Block\User\Edit\Tab\Main $subject,
    \Closure $proceed
) {
    $_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $registry = $_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry');
    $model = $registry->registry('permissions_user');
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $form = $subject->getForm();
    if (is_object($form)) {
            $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('user_attribute_fieldset', ['legend' => __('User Category')]);
            // Gather our existing categories
            $currentCategories = $this->_getExistingCategories($model);
            $fieldset->addField(
                'user_fields',
                'multiselect',
                [
                    'name' => 'user_fields',
                    'label' => __('user fields'),
                    'id' => 'user_fields',
                    'title' => __('user fields'),
                    'value' => $currentCategories,//for selected value
                    'values' => $objectManager->create('{namespace}\{module}\Helper\Data')->getOptions()//for all options
                ]
            );
             $subject->setForm($form);

    }
    return $proceed();
}
```

Now I want to create this as a Multi Select UI Field, shown below:
[image]

how I can implement ui select component in existing magento forms not made with ui components?

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: I ain't sure but you can't add `ui_component` in form developed using **PHP**, You need to create whole form with `ui_component` than you can add **Multiselect** as you mentioned in question.

Comment: But its magento's default form, how can I recreate the whole form through UI component?

Comment: Hello. Did you solved this issue? I face same issue. Can you please post answer if you sovled already?

Comment: @Denish please check my answer, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly add a field in your ui-form:

```
<field name="custom" component="Namespce_Modulename/js/select-category" sortOrder="20" formElement="select">
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
 <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="filterOptions" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
     //to add filter in select-ui
    <item name="multiple" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>//select multiple or not
    <item name="showCheckbox" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>//to show checkboxes
    <item name="disableLabel" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
</item>
</argument>
<settings>
<required>true</required>
<validation>
    <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
</validation>
<elementTmpl>ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</elementTmpl>
<label translate="true">Select Category</label>//label to Field
<dataScope>data.custom</dataScope>//To map
<componentType>field</componentType>
<listens>
    <link name="${ $.namespace }.${ $.namespace }:responseData">setParsed</link>
</listens>
</settings>
<formElements>
<select>
    <settings>
        <options class="Namespace\ModuleName\Ui\Component\Form\Category\Options"/>
    </settings>
</select>
 </formElements>
```

Now create Js file to map the field's value:

Namespace_Modulename/view/adminhtml/web/js/select-category.js

```
define([
'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/ui-select'
], function (Select) {
'use strict';
return Select.extend({
/**
 * Parse data and set it to options.
 *
 * @param {Object} data - Response data object.
 * @returns {Object}
 */
setParsed: function (data) {
    var option = this.parseData(data);
    if (data.error) {
        return this;
    }
    this.options([]);
    this.setOption(option);
    this.set('newOption', option);
},
/**
 * Normalize option object.
 *
 * @param {Object} data - Option object.
 * @returns {Object}
 */
parseData: function (data) {
    return {
        value: data.category.entity_id,
        label: data.category.name
    };
}
});
});
```

Create a file to get options to display:

Namespace\ModuleName\Ui\Component\Form\Category\Options.php

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\ModuleName\Ui\Component\Form\Category;

use Magento\Framework\Data\OptionSourceInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory as         CategoryCollectionFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;

/**
 * Options tree for "Categories" field
*/
class Options implements OptionSourceInterface
{

protected $categoryCollectionFactory;

 /**
  * @var RequestInterface
 */
 protected $request;

 /**
 * @var array
 */
 protected $categoryTree;

 /**
  * @param CategoryCollectionFactory $categoryCollectionFactory
  * @param RequestInterface $request
  */
public function __construct(
CategoryCollectionFactory $categoryCollectionFactory,
RequestInterface $request
) {
$this->categoryCollectionFactory = $categoryCollectionFactory;
$this->request = $request;
}

/**
* {@inheritdoc}
*/
public function toOptionArray()
{
return $this->getCategoryTree();
}


/**
* Retrieve categories tree
*
* @return array
*/
protected function getCategoryTree()
{
if ($this->categoryTree === null) {
    $collection = $this->categoryCollectionFactory->create();

    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('name');

    foreach ($collection as $category) {
        $categoryId = $category->getEntityId();
        if (!isset($categoryById[$categoryId])) {
            $categoryById[$categoryId] = [
                'value' => $categoryId
            ];
        }
        $categoryById[$categoryId]['label'] = $category->getName();
    }
    $this->categoryTree = $categoryById;
   }
   return $this->categoryTree;
   }
 }
```

Hope it helps!!!